# Docker with self contained ASP.NET app failed to create shim task

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I'm trying to change the [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/) reference project to build Docker images that use self contained apps instead of framework dependent.

This is the working Dockerfile that comes with the Identity microservice:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

# It's important to keep lines from here down to "COPY . ." identical in all Dockerfiles
# to take advantage of Docker's build cache, to speed up local container builds
COPY "eShopOnContainers-ServicesAndWebApps.sln" "eShopOnContainers-ServicesAndWebApps.sln"

COPY "ApiGateways/Mobile.Bff.Shopping/aggregator/Mobile.Shopping.HttpAggregator.csproj" "ApiGateways/Mobile.Bff.Shopping/aggregator/Mobile.Shopping.HttpAggregator.csproj"
COPY "ApiGateways/Web.Bff.Shopping/aggregator/Web.Shopping.HttpAggregator.csproj" "ApiGateways/Web.Bff.Shopping/aggregator/Web.Shopping.HttpAggregator.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/Devspaces.Support/Devspaces.Support.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/Devspaces.Support/Devspaces.Support.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus/EventBus.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus/EventBus.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus.Tests/EventBus.Tests.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus.Tests/EventBus.Tests.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusRabbitMQ/EventBusRabbitMQ.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusRabbitMQ/EventBusRabbitMQ.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusServiceBus/EventBusServiceBus.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusServiceBus/EventBusServiceBus.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/IntegrationEventLogEF/IntegrationEventLogEF.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/IntegrationEventLogEF/IntegrationEventLogEF.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/WebHostCustomization/WebHost.Customization/WebHost.Customization.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/WebHostCustomization/WebHost.Customization/WebHost.Customization.csproj"
COPY "Services/Basket/Basket.API/Basket.API.csproj" "Services/Basket/Basket.API/Basket.API.csproj"
COPY "Services/Basket/Basket.FunctionalTests/Basket.FunctionalTests.csproj" "Services/Basket/Basket.FunctionalTests/Basket.FunctionalTests.csproj"
COPY "Services/Basket/Basket.UnitTests/Basket.UnitTests.csproj" "Services/Basket/Basket.UnitTests/Basket.UnitTests.csproj"
COPY "Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Catalog.API.csproj" "Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Catalog.API.csproj"
COPY "Services/Catalog/Catalog.FunctionalTests/Catalog.FunctionalTests.csproj" "Services/Catalog/Catalog.FunctionalTests/Catalog.FunctionalTests.csproj"
COPY "Services/Catalog/Catalog.UnitTests/Catalog.UnitTests.csproj" "Services/Catalog/Catalog.UnitTests/Catalog.UnitTests.csproj"
COPY "Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj" "Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.API/Ordering.API.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.API/Ordering.API.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.BackgroundTasks/Ordering.BackgroundTasks.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.BackgroundTasks/Ordering.BackgroundTasks.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.Domain/Ordering.Domain.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.Domain/Ordering.Domain.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.FunctionalTests/Ordering.FunctionalTests.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.FunctionalTests/Ordering.FunctionalTests.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.Infrastructure/Ordering.Infrastructure.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.Infrastructure/Ordering.Infrastructure.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.SignalrHub/Ordering.SignalrHub.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.SignalrHub/Ordering.SignalrHub.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.UnitTests/Ordering.UnitTests.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.UnitTests/Ordering.UnitTests.csproj"
COPY "Services/Payment/Payment.API/Payment.API.csproj" "Services/Payment/Payment.API/Payment.API.csproj"
COPY "Services/Webhooks/Webhooks.API/Webhooks.API.csproj" "Services/Webhooks/Webhooks.API/Webhooks.API.csproj"
COPY "Tests/Services/Application.FunctionalTests/Application.FunctionalTests.csproj" "Tests/Services/Application.FunctionalTests/Application.FunctionalTests.csproj"
COPY "Web/WebhookClient/WebhookClient.csproj" "Web/WebhookClient/WebhookClient.csproj"
COPY "Web/WebMVC/WebMVC.csproj" "Web/WebMVC/WebMVC.csproj"
COPY "Web/WebSPA/WebSPA.csproj" "Web/WebSPA/WebSPA.csproj"
COPY "Web/WebStatus/WebStatus.csproj" "Web/WebStatus/WebStatus.csproj"

COPY "docker-compose.dcproj" "docker-compose.dcproj"

COPY "NuGet.config" "NuGet.config"

RUN dotnet restore "eShopOnContainers-ServicesAndWebApps.sln"

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Services/Identity/Identity.API
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Identity.API.dll"]
```

Now instead I'm trying to use runtime-deps:6.0-alpine and the sdk:6.0-alpine as base images, and run a different publish command:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:6.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src

# It's important to keep lines from here down to "COPY . ." identical in all Dockerfiles
# to take advantage of Docker's build cache, to speed up local container builds
COPY "eShopOnContainers-ServicesAndWebApps.sln" "eShopOnContainers-ServicesAndWebApps.sln"

COPY "ApiGateways/Mobile.Bff.Shopping/aggregator/Mobile.Shopping.HttpAggregator.csproj" "ApiGateways/Mobile.Bff.Shopping/aggregator/Mobile.Shopping.HttpAggregator.csproj"
COPY "ApiGateways/Web.Bff.Shopping/aggregator/Web.Shopping.HttpAggregator.csproj" "ApiGateways/Web.Bff.Shopping/aggregator/Web.Shopping.HttpAggregator.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/Devspaces.Support/Devspaces.Support.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/Devspaces.Support/Devspaces.Support.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus/EventBus.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus/EventBus.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus.Tests/EventBus.Tests.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBus.Tests/EventBus.Tests.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusRabbitMQ/EventBusRabbitMQ.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusRabbitMQ/EventBusRabbitMQ.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusServiceBus/EventBusServiceBus.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusServiceBus/EventBusServiceBus.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/IntegrationEventLogEF/IntegrationEventLogEF.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/EventBus/IntegrationEventLogEF/IntegrationEventLogEF.csproj"
COPY "BuildingBlocks/WebHostCustomization/WebHost.Customization/WebHost.Customization.csproj" "BuildingBlocks/WebHostCustomization/WebHost.Customization/WebHost.Customization.csproj"
COPY "Services/Basket/Basket.API/Basket.API.csproj" "Services/Basket/Basket.API/Basket.API.csproj"
COPY "Services/Basket/Basket.FunctionalTests/Basket.FunctionalTests.csproj" "Services/Basket/Basket.FunctionalTests/Basket.FunctionalTests.csproj"
COPY "Services/Basket/Basket.UnitTests/Basket.UnitTests.csproj" "Services/Basket/Basket.UnitTests/Basket.UnitTests.csproj"
COPY "Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Catalog.API.csproj" "Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Catalog.API.csproj"
COPY "Services/Catalog/Catalog.FunctionalTests/Catalog.FunctionalTests.csproj" "Services/Catalog/Catalog.FunctionalTests/Catalog.FunctionalTests.csproj"
COPY "Services/Catalog/Catalog.UnitTests/Catalog.UnitTests.csproj" "Services/Catalog/Catalog.UnitTests/Catalog.UnitTests.csproj"
COPY "Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj" "Services/Identity/Identity.API/Identity.API.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.API/Ordering.API.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.API/Ordering.API.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.BackgroundTasks/Ordering.BackgroundTasks.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.BackgroundTasks/Ordering.BackgroundTasks.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.Domain/Ordering.Domain.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.Domain/Ordering.Domain.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.FunctionalTests/Ordering.FunctionalTests.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.FunctionalTests/Ordering.FunctionalTests.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.Infrastructure/Ordering.Infrastructure.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.Infrastructure/Ordering.Infrastructure.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.SignalrHub/Ordering.SignalrHub.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.SignalrHub/Ordering.SignalrHub.csproj"
COPY "Services/Ordering/Ordering.UnitTests/Ordering.UnitTests.csproj" "Services/Ordering/Ordering.UnitTests/Ordering.UnitTests.csproj"
COPY "Services/Payment/Payment.API/Payment.API.csproj" "Services/Payment/Payment.API/Payment.API.csproj"
COPY "Services/Webhooks/Webhooks.API/Webhooks.API.csproj" "Services/Webhooks/Webhooks.API/Webhooks.API.csproj"
COPY "Tests/Services/Application.FunctionalTests/Application.FunctionalTests.csproj" "Tests/Services/Application.FunctionalTests/Application.FunctionalTests.csproj"
COPY "Web/WebhookClient/WebhookClient.csproj" "Web/WebhookClient/WebhookClient.csproj"
COPY "Web/WebMVC/WebMVC.csproj" "Web/WebMVC/WebMVC.csproj"
COPY "Web/WebSPA/WebSPA.csproj" "Web/WebSPA/WebSPA.csproj"
COPY "Web/WebStatus/WebStatus.csproj" "Web/WebStatus/WebStatus.csproj"

COPY "docker-compose.dcproj" "docker-compose.dcproj"

COPY "NuGet.config" "NuGet.config"

RUN dotnet restore "eShopOnContainers-ServicesAndWebApps.sln"

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Services/Identity/Identity.API
RUN dotnet publish --self-contained --runtime linux-musl-x64 -c Release -o /app -p:PublishTrimmed=true

FROM build AS publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Identity.API.dll"]
```

When I run this docker image though, I get the following error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI
> runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container
> process: exec: "dotnet": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you also have to change the ENTRYPOINT when switching to self-contained Docker apps

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Identity.API.dll"]
```

was changed to

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./Identity.API"]
```

and it worked

Comment: Just in case it can help anybody else, in my case, I was doing:
ENTRYPOINT ["MyApp"]
Had to change to the following to make it work:
ENTRYPOINT ["./MyApp"]